# Reboot and select proper boot device, Ubuntu not loading

Tags: dual-boot, bios, reboot

I am using a really old laptop. I recently installed Ubuntu in a laptop which already has Windows 10. After installing Ubuntu, I was not able to load Windows even though it was present in the drive, so I started using Ubuntu and it worked fine, but this morning I got this issue:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device \
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_
```

[image]

I woant to get all my data back, and currently my last resort is to fresh install a new version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows has a habit of leaving hardware in an "intermediary state", which makes it difficult to switch operating systems with a simple reboot. You may have better luck by booting into Windows, then choosing "Shut Down" (*not* Restart), letting the machine come to a complete resting state, then booting into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the laptop is not trying to boot from the harddrive. You can select your boot devices in the BIOS. After starting the laptop you have to repeatedly press a certain key ( depends on the laptop Esc, F2, F10, Delete ). Once it boots from the harddrive it will boot into Grub(2). In the menu you can choose which OS you want to boot ( Ubuntu or Windows ).

When you say 'I started using Ubuntu', did you start it up from the harddrive, or did you use a live version from cd/dvd or usb?